# event handling in infinite while loop in python2

Tags: python, python-2.7

want to handle an event in infinite while loop in python2 without using multithreading.

```
import pjsua as pj,soundfile as sf
import sys,threading,speech_to_text,sys,settings,text_to_speech,create_requests,common_functions,os,time,threading
from pydub import AudioSegment
...
...
...
class MyAccountCallback(pj.AccountCallback):
    sem = None

    def __init__(self, account):
        pj.AccountCallback.__init__(self, account)

    def on_incoming_call(self, call):
        global current_call
        current_call = call
        call_cb = MyCallCallback(current_call)
        current_call.set_callback(call_cb)
        current_call.answer(180)
        current_call.answer(200)
        time.sleep(2)

        listen_and_respond()

class MyCallCallback(pj.CallCallback):

    def __init__(self, call=None):
        pj.CallCallback.__init__(self,call)

    def on_state(self):
        global current_call,CallerID
        print "Call with", self.call.info().remote_uri,
        print "is", self.call.info().state_text,
        print "last code = ", self.call.info().last_code,
        print "(" + self.call.info().last_reason + ")"
        index_at_the_rate=(self.call.info().remote_uri).find('@')
        CallerID=(self.call.info().remote_uri)[5:index_at_the_rate]

        if self.call.info().state == 6:
            print "Call Cut from user end"

def listen_and_respond():
    while true:
        # some code here
...
...
...
```

Here is a code which i am working on : to handle a voice bot on phone call.
There are 2 classes.

MyAccountCallback --- handles the event.
MyCallCallback --- handles the state change.

Now suppose the user dial the number to contact the bot
the state change happens and triggers the function "on incoming call".

But when the callstack enters the while loop and the user cut the phone call then it does not print the state change results. state change does not happens

and thus the programmer is not able to print the exact ending message.

The code is in python2.
I dont want to use multithreading.

Can anyone help me out how to handle the state\event change inside the infinite while loop.

Comment: Not wanting to use `asyncio` is not a good reason for choosing to write in Python 2.

Comment: Please post a proper minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)